# php voting system - database trouble

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a voting system for my site. I'm not exactly sure how to set up the Database tables, so that 1 user can either like or dislike a certain post(and he can either like/dislike any other posts (but only once - can't like/dislike a post more than once)).

I have a users table where 'username' is the primary key. 
Then I have posts table with following columns: post_text, timestamp, post_id (this is the primary key), user_name (FK is username from users table), category, posvotes, negvotes
last table is votes table: username (FK is username from users table), post_id (FK is post_id from posts table), votedpos, votedneg.

I am really not sure if the table is set up correctly for this to work.

here is my php code: (It's an older code, the queries will be changed to mysqli statements, so don't mind the deprecated mysql statements)
 $post_id and $user_name are working correctly and have the current username and post_id.

```
$post_id = $_SESSION['post_id'];
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
if(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id='".$post_id."' AND user_name='".$user_name."' AND(SELECT * FROM votes WHERE post_id='".$post_id."' AND votedpos=0)"))
{
$vote = "UPDATE posts SET posvotes=posvotes+1 WHERE post_id='".$post_id."'"; 
$runvote = mysql_query($vote) or die("error");
$safe = "UPDATE votes SET votedpos=1 WHERE post_id='".$post_id."'";
$runsafe = mysql_query($safe);
if(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id='".$post_id."' AND user_name='".$user_name."' AND(SELECT * FROM votes WHERE votedpos>0 AND username='".$user_name."')"))      //if u +voted, then fail
{
    echo "cant vote twice";
}
else
{
    if(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id='".$post_id."' AND user_name='".$user_name."' AND (SELECT * FROM votes WHERE negvotes>0 AND username='".$user_name."')"))     //if u negvoted previously, change your vote to plusvote
    {
        $vote = "UPDATE posts SET posvotes=posvotes+1 WHERE post_id='".$post_id."'"; 
        $runvote = mysql_query($vote);
        mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET negvotes=negvotes-1 WHERE post_id='".$post_id."'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE votes SET votedneg=0 WHERE post_id='".$post_id."'");
        $safe = "UPDATE votes SET votedpos=1 WHERE post_id='".$post_id."'";
        $runsafe = mysql_query($safe);
    }
}
}
```

For disliking a post I have the same script (except where the positive votes are the negative ones will be). But I can't get this one to work and don't know if my table set up is wrong or my php coding.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I like it how you have `safe` in your code while it really is not :)

Comment: oh. it's supposed to be named save :)

Answer (score 0):

If your change your votes table to use username and post_id as the primary key with an enum (vote_up, neutral, vote_down) for the voting value then it seems to solve the problem without pushing the logic up into PHP and polling the state of existing data.